# Communications link failure by Mulesoft 4.x only in localhost

Tags: mysql, mulesoft

I'm using mulesoft 4.x. I have the following problem: I can't get it to connect to mysql server in localhost, but I can get it to connect on remote hosts without problem. However, that server "localhost" works correctly so much that it is reachable by the mulesoft runtime if I move it to another machine.

the error is: **Caused by: org.mule.runtime.extension.api.exception.ModuleException: java.sql.SQLException: Cannot get connection for URL jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/test?logger=org.mule.extension.db.api.logger.MuleMySqlLogger : Communications link failure**

Example: VM with ip 10.0.2.200 and mulesoft runtime installed with MYSQL. mulesoft does not connect, but if I move mulesoft to a different server with ip 10.0.2.202, it connects to Mysql on 10.0.2.200

Comment: Looks to be a problem in the configuration of firewall rules of the VM or MySQL configuration.

Comment: I solved it, the problem was that mysql had ssl enabled and in the mulesoft connector I had to expressly set the "useSSL" property to false. (this only in localhost, this is a mystery)